# How to make a sidebar form show at the top of page on mobile?

Tags: css

There is a quote request form on the sidebar of homepage and all other pages. On mobile and tablets, this form used to show on the top. But something changed and now it shows on the bottom of page when using mobile. Only the homepage remains to show it on the top. All other pages show on bottom. Not sure what changed, but I would like to have it back on the top of page for mobile viewers.

Here is what it looks like: http://prntscr.com/o0ywj8

Anyone know how to get this to show on top of page for mobile?

Comment: Inspect the element and compare the classes and rules applied to the homepage vs the other pages and it should tell you whats different, that should lead you to what needs adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more, I can't tell you if this is a theme setting or plugin update that changed this, or if the code literally was changed, or why the homepage works but the rest doesn't.

I can tell you from the provided screenshot that the necessary bootstrap that would swap the positions isn't there. [See their reordering guide for bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering). If you have the ability to edit the template, you should be able to apply this and have it ordered properly.